# Set the symbol horizontally \square (and more closer) using mtpro2

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mathtools, mtpro, amssymb

My question is very short and it is not a duplicate because I want the symbol `\square` with a better position using `mtpro2` package which it is not perfect. Infact if I use the symbol `\square` for the Dalambertian operator with this MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\square\cdot (fX)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

the square symbol (`\square`) is small because I'm using `\usepackage{newtxmath}`, but is a bit far from the `\cdot` symbol but is in line with all the characters. 
Obviously I could insert a negative space before `\cdot` but I would like to avoid doing so. But using the package `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`, the symbol `\square` change but it's bigger than the previous symbol and different.

How is it possible to have a square symbol (better centered) that aesthetically fits better as a Dalambertian operator and is closer to the dot of `\cdot`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\square\cdot (fX)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why use a font whose behaviour you don't like?

Comment: @ufo I like very much mtpro2 font. My questions are founded, often, on this font.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)

Comment: Maybe employ a macro that does this: `\vcenter{\hbox{$\square$}}\!\cdot`.  Sorry, I can't help as i don't have `mtpro2` font.  Alternately, you could save the old `\square` before loading `mtpro2` and use that instead.

Comment: The distance is caused by the binary operator `\cdot` and not by `\square`. Except for `\!` there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: Perhaps writing `{\cdot}` would give you the desired spacing

Comment: @AndrewSwann Another answers for me are welcome, always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just writing `{\cdot}` rather than `\cdot` gives you the desired spacing.  I don't have `mtpro2`, so this is with your original code:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\square{\cdot} (fX)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\mathop{\square\cdot}`? This makes a reasonable spacing with the symbol before.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own square symbol with a definable size very easily by using `\fbox`, you can adjust it to your liking by changing the `\fboxrule` thickness and the size of the `\phantom`ed `\rule`.

With this definition the size of the symbol doesn't change in sub or super script.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newlength\mysquaresize
\newcommand\mysquare
  {%
    \begingroup
    \fboxrule=.12ex
    \mysquaresize=1ex
    \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
    \vcenter{\hbox{\fbox{\phantom{\rule{\mysquaresize}{\mysquaresize}}}}}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\mysquare\cdot (fX)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A version in which you can also define sizes in the different math modes:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,11pt]{standalone}

\newlength\mysquaresize
\newcommand\mysquare
  {%
    \mathchoice
      {\mysquareaux{.12ex}{1ex}}
      {\mysquareaux{.12ex}{1ex}}
      {\mysquareaux{.11ex}{.8ex}}
      {\mysquareaux{.10ex}{.7ex}}%
  }
  \newcommand\mysquareaux[2]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \fboxrule=#1
    \mysquaresize=#2
    \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
    \vcenter{\hbox{\fbox{\phantom{\rule{\mysquaresize}{\mysquaresize}}}}}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
$
\displaystyle
L'=L+\mu_{0}\mysquare\cdot (fX)
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Always thank you also to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can import a symbol from another font. But the space after the square is not triggered by the square but by the binary symbol. If you would change the definition of \square to suppress this space it would give bad results if ordinary symbols are after the square:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSm}{U}{ntxsym}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ntxsquare} {\mathord}{AMSm}{131}

\begin{document}
\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\ntxsquare\cdot (fX)
\]


\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\ntxsquare\mathpunct{\cdot} (fX)
\]


\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\ntxsquare\!\cdot (fX)
\]

\[
L'=L+\mu_{0}\ntxsquare\! x (fX) %bad
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer. Excuse me very much but I have taken the shorter answer with the check green. Always thank you.